# Ag-grid how to update cell style by clicking a button

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I have a button on top of my grid and I want to update cell style depending on cell value once clicked. I have something working but it updates all columns and not specific cell. How can I update/target specific cell when I click on the button.

```
updateCellStyle(){ this.gridApi.getColumnDef(column).cellStyle = { border: '1px solid #165a9f' }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have'nt tested but I believe its something like this; set `buttonClicked` to true on button click.

```
const gridOptions = {
    ....
    context: {
        buttonClicked: false
    }
};
```

In the columnDef:

```
cellStyle: params => params.context.buttonClicked && params.value > 80 ? 
    { border: '1px solid #165a9f' } : { border: 'whatever it is before the button is clicked' }
```

Comment: Thanks this would work if you know the exact column, my columns are dynamic and depending on that I need to highlight cell

Comment: I don't understand your case then, don't you have a columnDef for every column? if so, add above cellStyle to only those columnDefs where you want color based on cell value.